# Is O(n log n) exponential speedup over O(n^2)?

Tags: complexity-theory, polynomials, big-o-notation

I would like to know if $O(n \log n)$ is an exponential speedup over $O(n^2)$?

Comment: No. It’s a polynomial speedup.

Comment: I suppose you are correct, the first term is dominated by a linear term, while the log n term is negligible, so the speedup for large n looks approximately like n^2 vs Cn for some constant C, but I'd like an answer in terms of formal definitions and workings.

Comment: How do I show that this is a polynomial speedup formally? Is it precisely a polynomial speedup or is there a more accurate term to describe it, like I don't know, subpolynomial?

Comment: You improved $f(n)$ to roughly $\sqrt{f(n)}$. This is a polynomial improvement. An exponential improvement would have been something like $\log f(n)$.

Comment: Can you add more explanation on why you think n log n is an exponential speedup over n^2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$O(n \log n)$ is a *polynomial* speedup over $O(n^2)$, in particular almost a *quadratic* speedup. $O(n \log n)$ is big-O of $O(n^k$) for all $k > 1$. Its runtime is therefore between linear and any powerfunction whose exponent is strictly greater than 1.

Let $f(n)=n \log n$. Raise it to a power of some value slightly less than 2 to approximate the original runtime. We conclude $f(n) \approx n^{2-\varepsilon} (\log n)^{2-\varepsilon}$ and in $O(n^2)$. If we square $f(n)$, we have $n^2 (\log n)^2$, slightly less efficient than the original $n^2$, hence it is basically a quadratic speedup.

Instead, $O(\log n^2) = O(\log n)$ is an exponential speedup over $O(n^2)$. If $g(n) = 2\log(n)$, then $e^{g(n)} = n^2$.

Comment: I see, it is an almost quadratic speedup in the sense that the original function raised to any power less than 2 will be in $O(n^2),$ in fact $o(n^2)$.

That's because for $n$ large enough, $(\log n )/ n^k < \epsilon$, $k>0$, since $n < e^{\epsilon n^k} $ for n large enough. That's because, there an integer N, $kN > 1$, so that the term in the taylor expansion of the exponential term has $\epsilon^N n^{kN}/N! > n$ for $n^{kN-1} > N!/\epsilon^{N}$

Comment: @Rascalniikov Thank you very much ! I sent a suggested edit to you, please accept it, or improve the edit to make further explanation.